# Interpreting in higher dimensions with maximal spacing

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning

I have data that I would like to interpret in higher dimension (sort of the opposite of an auto-encoder). What I intent to achieve is, an `m` dimension data being represented in `n` dimensions (`n>m`) with the constraint that the representation in the `n` dimensions is maximally separated.

For clarity, I will assume the binary field. My data has `m=20` dimensions. I would like to represent this data in a `n=50` dimensional space. There are `2^m` number of data combinations that are possible and `2^n` number of points in the larger dimension. My goal is to select `2^m` points from `2^n` points, which are as far away from each other as possible.

I am versed with neural networks. What I want to know is how do I tackle this problem from a neural network perspective? Thanks!